# Получение sip-сообщений в asterisk

Tags: asterisk, sip

Я хочу отправлять sip-сообщения с одного астериска на второй. Отправка происходит через команду MessageSend, а вот как обработать получение сообщения на втором астериске, если он зарегистрирован как пир на первом?

Comment: Через ami (asterisk management interface)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте MESSAGE() в диалплане на стороне получателя.

> This function will read from or write a value to a text message. It is
>   used both to read the data out of an incoming message, as well as
>   modify or create a message that will be sent outbound.

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+11+Function_MESSAGE